# I make my raspberry-pi to be Access Point, but How can Android Phone communicate with raspberry-pi?

Tags: server

As the title say,

I made my raspberry-pi to be Access Point, but **How can Android Phone communicate with raspberry-pi ?**

For example, Should I insert some python file or PHP file to raspberry pi and send post data to ra-pi by using Android HTTP Library(Volley) like we usually do with apache server?

---

My purpose scenario is this.

Android App : "this is wifi ssid and password"

Raspberry Pi : "thank you , wait .... Oh, password is not right, please give me again"

Android App : "OK, Here !"

Raspberry Pi : "thank you, wait .... OK GOOD, Now I connected with your home's wifi!"

---

these are what I found

1. android - raspberry pi socket communication

   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8THp3mhbdA
2. smart plug( from 4:40 ~ )

   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKiTH5OwbuA&t=262s

Comment: what type of communication do you want between the RPi and the android phone? you want to view a web page?

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for your reply, I edit my question

Comment: So, what protocol is that?

Comment: @JaromandaX  I am not goot at network, but,,, may be HTTP? or DHCP?

Comment: No, DHCP would be useful for that sort of communication. HTTP, possibly, but you'd possibly have to write an APP for the android. As far as the example "communication" goes. How would the Raspberry Pi receive a wifi ssid/password without already being connected to the network? Is it connected through ethernet? if so, why does it need ssid/password?

Comment: @JaromandaX Raspberry-Pi will be connected with Android APP by making Raspberry Pi to be Access Point !  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKiTH5OwbuA&t=262s (from 4:40~) <- check please

Comment: d'oh - pays to read the question doesn't it :p